# Laravel 5 forms: generate fieldv value instead of having user fill in

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a form that has a field that is required (trip_route_name).  I want to generate a name for this (say a random number for example) when the form is submited rather than having the user fill out the form.  How do I do that?  Here is the code for the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::label('trip_route_name', 'Trip Route Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text( 'trip_route_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        <p      id="msg_trip_route_name" class="text-danger">{!! $errors->first('trip_route_name', ':message') !!}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str_random()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-random) helper:

```
{!! Form::text( 'trip_route_name', str_random(20), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

> The `str_random` function generates a random string of the specified length.

If you don't want user could see generated random name, use `hidden` instead of `text`.

Comment: AH alright, and what if I want to set the value to one of the other fields values?